# Запрос на выборку из БД "Склад" SQL

Tags: sql

Имеется следующая БД
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К ней необходимо написать запрос "Отчет по каждому товару об общем количестве раз покупки этого товара и количестве поступлений". Покупка или поступление определяется атрибутом "Тип сделки" в таблице "Накладные". Информация о количестве и о конкретном поступившем или проданном товаре содержится в таблице "Записи списка"
Имеются следующие тестовые данные этой БД:

```
--Фирмы
    insert into [Фирмы] ([Адрес офиса],[Наименование]) values ('г.Москва, ул.Зенитчиков, д.21','ООО "Винотек"')
    --Склады
    insert into [Склады] ([Адрес],[Id фирмы]) values ('г.Москва, ул.Шеногина, д.24', 1)
    
--Кладовщики
    insert into [Кладовщики] ([ФИО],[Номер телефона]) values ('Бондаренко Владимир Матвеевич', '+7 495 2250291')

--Товары
    insert into [Товары] ([Наименование],[Цена]) values ('Вино Le Petit Mouton" De Mouton Rothschild, 2016', 66490)
    insert into [Товары] ([Наименование],[Цена]) values ('Вино Domaine Ponsot, "Cuvee du Bourdon" Corton Grand Cru AOC, 2015', 66150)
    
--Контрагенты
    insert into [Контрагенты] ([ИНН], [Наименование], [Адрес]) values (0344114013, 'ПАО "Возвышенность', 'г.Москва, ул.Будайская, д.62')

--Накладные
    insert into [Накладные] ([Id контрагента], [Id кладовщика], [Id склада], [Тип сделки], [Дата]) values (1,1,1,'Поставка','2020-12-17')
    insert into [Накладные] ([Id контрагента], [Id кладовщика], [Id склада], [Тип сделки], [Дата]) values (1,1,1,'Покупка','2020-09-15')

--Записи списка
    insert into [Записи списка] ([Id накладной],[Id товара],[Единица измерения],[Количество]) values (1,1,'шт.',10)
    insert into [Записи списка] ([Id накладной],[Id товара],[Единица измерения],[Количество]) values (1,1,'шт.',5)
    insert into [Записи списка] ([Id накладной],[Id товара],[Единица измерения],[Количество]) values (2,1,'шт.',5)
    insert into [Записи списка] ([Id накладной],[Id товара],[Единица измерения],[Количество]) values (2,1,'шт.',10)
    insert into [Записи списка] ([Id накладной],[Id товара],[Единица измерения],[Количество]) values (1,2,'шт.',30)
    insert into [Записи списка] ([Id накладной],[Id товара],[Единица измерения],[Количество]) values (2,2,'шт.',5)
```

Моя попытка реализации запроса о количестве раз поставки товара (не работает):

```
select [Товары].[Наименование], 
( select sum([Количество]) from [Товары],[Записи списка],[Накладные] where [Записи списка].[Id накладной] = [Накладные].Id and [Записи списка].[Id товара] = [Товары].[Id] and [Накладные].[Тип сделки] = 'Поставка' ) as 'Поставлен раз'
from [Товары],[Записи списка],[Накладные] where [Записи списка].[Id накладной] = [Накладные].Id and [Записи списка].[Id товара] = [Товары].[Id] group by [Товары].[Наименование]
```

Результат:
[image: Результат запроса]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подзапрос явно тут лишний. В результате соединений вся информация уже есть. Запрос примет следующий вид:

```
select
    [Товары].[Наименование],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Накладные].[Тип сделки] = 'Поставка' THEN [Записи списка].[Количество] END) as 'Поставлен раз'
FROM from [Товары],[Записи списка],[Накладные]
where [Записи списка].[Id накладной] = [Накладные].Id 
    and [Записи списка].[Id товара] = [Товары].[Id]
group by [Товары].[Id], [Товары].[Наименование];
```